# Chrome loading long time to get into dashboard

Tags: php, google-chrome

I recently added a new mysqli query to my website. After that especially in chrome when i input the correct pass and account name, it takes long load(long loading) and not even redirect me into the dashboard. But it was working fine before. Meanwhile, when i tested in firefox and other browsers, I am not faceing  that issue. I mean, in firefox and Microsoft Edge, it's working good and fast.
I even tried removing the query I lastly added and even deleted my chrome data. But still, i can't figure out what's the issue in chrome. Also i don't have any extensions.

Comment: Try opening the  dev tools, right-click on the refresh button and Empty Cach and Hard Reload

Comment: It would help if you shared the URL of the site the problem can be reproduced at. I too have issues with Chrome, but are they same issues? Hard to tell, right?